# Ghostscript processing of files on Amazon S3 (using Ubuntu)

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ubuntu-10.04

I am experimenting with Ghostscript and processing files that must stay on Amazon S3 (my app is running on Heroku). I plan to use a ghostscript binary in my Heroku account that merges PDF documents stored on S3, like this:

> gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=3.pdf 1.pdf2.pdf

...where 1.pdf, 2.pdf and 3.pdf are all on S3.

Is this possible?

Could something like this work:

> gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=s3://mybucket/3.pdf s3://mybucket/1.pdf s3://mybucket/2.pdf

... with the credentials somehow being passed over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what I am trying to do is not practical or just not possible on Heroku. With additional research I found that it is possible to use the #{$Rails.root}/tmp folder on my Heroku Rails app as scratch pad to create my merged PDF document and then move it to S3.

The following is tested and working (assuming files 1.pdf, 2.pdf, and 3.pdf are already in the Rails tmp folder):

```
system("gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=#{Rails.root}/tmp/merged.pdf #{Rails.root}/tmp/1.pdf #{Rails.root}/tmp/2.pdf #{Rails.root}/tmp/3.pdf")
system("ls -al #{Rails.root}/tmp/")
file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/merged.pdf", "r")
data = file.read
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])   
AWS::S3::S3Object.store("merged.pdf",data,ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'], :access => :private)
```